# How do you get the scrapped Boethiah's quest in which you have to kill Elisif?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to get this quest, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

That quest is called **Boethiah's Bidding**.

There is **[a mod with the same name](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/65929) that restores the quest** and makes it completely playable ([SSE port](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/18854)).

And [here](https://www.imperial-library.info/content/skyrim-boethiahs-bidding) is a sort of transcript of the proceedings of the quest, in case you don't want to or can't mod.

Comment: @Skyrimnoob You're welcome! Be sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem!